# Why doesn't PSOC 5LP print this number?

Tags: psoc

I'm using CY8CKIT-050 PSOC 5LP development kit and I have this code:

```
#include "project.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    CyGlobalIntEnable; /* Enable global interrupts. */

    float32 test;

    LCD_Start();

    for(;;)
    {
        test = 0.1;
        sprintf(lineStr, "Test: %.2f", test);

        LCD_Position(1u, 0u);
        LCD_PrintString("                    ");

        LCD_Position(1u, 0u);
        LCD_PrintString(lineStr);

    }
```

But when I connect the LCD to the board, it doesn't appear `0.1`, but `0.`. However, when test=0.0, it apears `Test: 0.000000`.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Obviously the word `Test:` appears, but I thought it was so obvious that I didn't have to mention. It's displayed `Test: 0.`

Comment: If you look at the responses, you can see in the last one I have said that I even removed the word "Test:", but nothing changed

Comment: what happens if you use `sprintf(lineStr, "Test: %.2f", 0.1);`?

Comment: Nothing, the same result

Comment: What happens if you move the LCD_PrintString that blanks the display to before the for(;;) loop?

Comment: Just the same output

Comment: Have you tried other values (e.g. 2.5) or without the .2 precision specifier?

Comment: I have tried right now and it seems that anything appears after a nonzero digit. For example, for 2.5 doesn't appear anything (with and without the .2 especifier)

Comment: It looks to me like the floating point output is broken, since you say that it shows "0.000000" even when you have a ".2" precision specifier (so it should show "0.00").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92150/discussion-between-srl100-and-josemi).

Comment: Embedded toolchains typically omit floating point functionality from printf related functions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `test` is defaulting to an integer datatype, unless you have declared it otherwise in one of your header files. Your real literal, 0.1, is being truncated (i.e. floored, rounded-down) to integer 0.

You must declare `test` to be a floating-point datatype.

Comment: One more reason to read what the compiler warnings are about. :D

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the declaration of test, it is actually a float but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[Referring to an earlier version of the question text.]

"Test: 0." contains 8 characters (not including the nul at the end) - is this the width of your LCD?

Try using LCD_PrintString("0123456789ABCDEF"); and see how many characters are displayed.

Comment: It has 16 characters, so I think that's not a problem

Comment: Try the print anyway, you might find that your (software) driver only thinks that the display is 8 characters wide!

Comment: I even removed the word "Test:", but nothing changed.

Comment: where is `lineStr` defined?